# Populate picker info in TabbedPage (Xamarin forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, picker

I have been trying to transfer/populate data between tabbed pages.
The general idea of what I am trying to do is to insert a product info in "Insert/Edit" page which then can be viewed in the "Overview" page. The saved products are populated in a listview.

I am very new to MVVM and Xamarin.
The scenario I am having trouble with is when user click an item from the listview in "Overview" page, it should then populate the stored information in "Insert/Edit" page so that the user can edit the product info.
I was able to display most of the product info except for picker. It just showed empty.

[image]

Is my TabbedViewModel wrong? Can someone point me to a right direction?
Below is my tabbedpage xaml code.

```
<TabbedPage 
... 
...>
    <Views:InsertEdit Title="Insert/Edit" Icon="edit.png" BindingContext="{Binding productViewModel}"></Views:InsertEdit>
    <Views:Overview Title="Overview" Icon="list.png"></Views:Overview>
</TabbedPage>
```

I use a TabbedViewModel to bind product info between "Insert/Edit" page & "Overview" page

```
namespace Prototype
{
    public class TabbedViewModel
    {
        public Product productViewModel { set; get; }

        public TabbedViewModel(Product product)
        {
            productViewModel = product;
        }
    }
}
```

The product info is as per Product model

```
public class Product
{
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string productCode { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string merchant { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public string conditionCode { get; set; }
        public string conditionName { get; set; }
        
}
```

The product condition is as per ProductCondition model

```
public class ProductCondition
{
        
        public string conditionCode { get; set; }
        public string conditionName { get; set; }
        
}
```

In the picker list, only conditionName is displayed.
But when saving product info into the Product table, conditionName and conditionCode is stored together.

Below is my InsertEdit content page code

```
public partial class InsertEdit : ContentPage
{
    Product product;

    public InsertEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeData();
    }
    
    private async void InitializeData()
    {
        List<ProductCondition> conditionList = await App.DbHelper.GetConditionListAsync();
        picker.ItemsSource = conditionList;
    }

    // Upon clicking enter key in the entry text field, search for product info based on the product code user has keyed in
    async void EditorProductCode_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = ((Entry)sender).Text; //cast sender to access the properties of the Entry

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Warning", "Invalid", "OK");
        }
        else
        {

            product = await App.DbHelper.GetProduct(text);
            populateData();
        }
    }

    async void populateData() {
        if (product == null)
        {
            product = new Product();
            product = null;
            await DisplayAlert("Warning", "Invalid product code.", "OK");
        }

        picker.SelectedItem = ((List<ProductCondition>)picker.ItemsSource).FirstOrDefault(c => c.conditionCode == product.conditionCode);

        BindingContext = product;
    }

   
   // Upon clicking the save button
    async void OnSaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        product.conditionCode = ((ProductCondition)picker.SelectedItem).conditionCode;
        product.conditionName = ((ProductCondition)picker.SelectedItem).conditionName;
        await App.DbHelper.SaveProductAsync(product);

        DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().LongAlert("Product has been saved!");

    }

}
```

Below is the picker xaml code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Text="Product Condition" 
       HorizontalOptions="Start"
       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1"
       HorizontalOptions="Start"
       VerticalOptions="Center"
       Text=":"/>
    <Picker Grid.Column="2"
        Title="Select Condition" 
        x:Name="picker" 
        FontSize="13"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding conditionName}"
        />
</Grid>
```

Below is my InsertEdit content page code

```
public partial class Overview : ContentPage
{
    public Overview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        Quantity.Text = "Quantity : " + (await App.DbHelper.GetProductTableCount()).ToString();

        lvItems.BeginRefresh();

        List<Product> productList = await App.DbHelper.GetProductListAsync();

        lvItems.ItemsSource = productList;
        lvItems.EndRefresh();

    }

    async void OnListViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Product product = e.SelectedItem as Product;

            var tab = this.Parent as TabbedPage;
            tab.BindingContext = new TabbedViewModel(product);
            tab.CurrentPage = tab.Children[0];

            /*await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabbedPage
            {
                BindingContext = new TabbedViewModel(product)
            });*/
        }
    }
}
```

Really appreciates it if someone can point me to the correct direction. I have been trying for days and the code above are the best that I can come out with. I am just lost on how to populate picker info.

Answer (score 0):

Add ProductCondition class object in Product Class and then Populate.

```
public class Product
{
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string productCode { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string merchant { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public ProductCondition productCondition { get; set; }            
}
```

Add SelectedItem in your picker

```
<Picker Grid.Column="2"
        Title="Select Condition" 
        x:Name="picker" 
        FontSize="13"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding conditionName}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding MyItemSelected,Mode="TwoWay"}"
        />
```

ViewModel

```
private ProductCondition myItemSelected = new ProductCondition();

public ProductCondition MyItemSelected
{
  get => myItemSelected;
  set
  {
     myItemSelected = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("MyItemSelected");
  }
}
```

And then before you navigate

```
MyItemSelected = selectedProduct.productCondition;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for feedback. But may I know where should I put this line of code `MyItemSelected = selectedProduct.productCondition;` at?
Also, the `ViewModel` in your answer, is it the same with `TabbedViewModel` ? Or do I need to create a new class call `ViewModel`?

Comment: @K.Yen Put the line of code where you map the next page before navigation. and the view model code also in the page where the binding of page 2 is placed